# How to visit only decl nodes behind a specified class declaration in Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I'm writing a clang tool that parses a given interface header in C++, and I need to only visit the nodes behind the declaration of the given interface class (i.e. only the member functions that belongs to the class and its parameters, ignoring the includes, attributes, and other stuff).

I'm using a `RecursiveASTVisitor` inherited class, so all its traverse and visitor methods are available. Maybe I don't understand at all the behaviour of the `RecursiveASTVisitor`, but until now I've tried to override the `TraverseCXXRecordDecl`, then check if the `decl` name is the same that the interface I'm looking for and finally visit all its children nodes. In this case the problem is that I don't know how to get an `iterator` or something that gives a reference to the children of a given `Decl`. I've looked in the API of clang, but I hadn't seen any function for this purpose. Also, I want to know if that is a good approach. Somebody has some other solution ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want, but you may use 2 traversals: one to find `CXXRecordDecl` and one to find what you want from this `CXXRecordDecl`. BTW, I think that member functions have a way to retrieve the parent `CXXRecordDecl`.

Comment: Thank you Jarod. I've also thought that approach but I didn't found a way to do it correctly, however it seems that your approach must be the correct one. Finally, I've done a provisional hack with a boolean but in a future I'll try to improve it.